# OpenGL ES 2D turning NDC into screen coordinates

Tags: matrix, vector, opengl-es, coordinates, viewport

I'm using OpenGL ES to draw only 2D shapes, and I have to create my own matrices and pass them to the shader.

I'm using only 3x3 matrices and 2 component vectors. I know that normally for 2D you'd still have 4x4 matrices and 3 component vectors with Z set to 1. But I'm wondering if I can keep it 3x3.

I've got all the matrices working, translation rotation and scale all work. What I'm missing is a "projection" matrix, all my positions are ranging from -1 to 1 and my shapes are deformed because my phone's aspect ratio isn't 1. I need a matrix that maps all my coordinates to the screen with the correct ratio.

Normally you'd use an orthographic projection matrix to do this mapping but those are all 4x4. How can I do this mapping with a 3x3 matrix? And if I can't is there any way to keep the matrices 3x3 and map it in some other way? (I could interpolate the coordinates without a matrix but that wouldn't fix the ratio problem)

To clarify, here is my vertex shader, as you can see I'm using a 3x3 transformation matrix and 2 component vectors:

```
uniform mat3 u_transform_mat;   

attribute vec2 a_vert_pos;  
attribute vec2 a_vert_uv;     

varying vec2 v_vert_uv;       

void main()                 
{                           
   v_vert_uv = a_vert_uv;       

   gl_Position = vec4(u_transform_mat * vec3(a_vert_pos, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your "projection" matrix really needs to do in this case is scale.

Say for example you have landscape screen dimensions, and your aspect ratio is 1.5. With the transformation you have now, the NDC range of [-1, 1] will be stretched out to fit the screen width, meaning that is scaled by a factor 1.5 in horizontal direction relative to the vertical direction.

What you want to keep the proportions intact is to map the range [-1.5, 1.5] in x-direction and the range [-1, 1] in y-direction to the screen. Or in the more general case, [-aspect, aspect] in x-direction.

To map the [-aspect, aspect] range to the NDC range of [-1, 1], you need to scale the x-coordinates by (1 / aspect). Your "projection" matrix is therefore a non-uniform scaling matrix that only scales in x-direction:

```
    [ 1.0f / aspectRatio  0.0f  0.0f ]
P = [        0.0f         1.0f  0.0f ]
    [        0.0f         0.0f  1.0f ]
```